# Emerald green trees too close?

Tags: trees

Landscaper installed emerald green trees approximately 2ft apart. I’m reading that it should be atleast 3ft. Can these trees survive being this close together?

[image: emerald green trees]

Comment: How far from the fence are these, and is the fence meant to be permanent?   Also, how tall do you want these to grow?

Comment: https://www.homefortheharvest.com/emerald-green-arborvitae-spacing/ is an interesting read - which starts by saying you want quite a bit of space between them compared to what you have, but if you scroll down it has information about tightly spaced trees which form a dense hedge but require frequent pruning.   If you are in a jurisdiction where you have strong consumer rights, I would consider asking the landscaper to redo this properly at their cost.

Comment: I have mine planted on three-foot centers and they took 7 years to even begin looking like a hedge. That said, I think two-foot centers are too close - sure, you'll get a hedge quicker, but then they'll start shading each other; the fence behind them will quickly shade out and kill the foliage in the back as well. Did the landscaper sell you the plants as well as plant them? If so, in my own opinion then you've been scammed - the landscaper planted them too close to sell you more plants. If not, then the landscaper is untrained/uneducated and should be avoided in the future.

Comment: Every other shrub needs moving inward or away.